# bash script condition check statement throwing error

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I am getting error in this line below

```
  BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
  TEST=$([[ "$BOOTPROTO" =~ (static|none|bootp|dhcp)$ ]] ; echo $?)
```

error I am getting is below

```
 -bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected argument `(' to conditional   binary operator
 -bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near `(s'
 -bash: command substitution: line 1: `[[ "$BOOTPROTO" =~ (static|none|bootp|dhcp)$ ]] ; echo $?'
```

I tried to run it manually but could not solve it

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Why go to such length just to get the test result?

Comment: I am trying to check if BOOTPROPTO contains static,none, dhcp etc..as it could contains anything from them, for giving example I set it to dhcp

Comment: Why not just: `[[ $BOOTPROTO =~ (static|none|bootp|dhcp)$ ]]; TEST=$?`

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your regex in quotes:

```
  BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
  TEST=$([[ "$BOOTPROTO" =~ "(static|none|bootp|dhcp)$" ]] ; echo $?)
  echo "$TEST"
```

Or if you are using Bash >= 3.2, then escape the parentheses (as Eric mentioned in the comments.)

```
TEST=$([[ "$BOOTPROTO" =~ \(static|none|bootp|dhcp\)$ ]] ; echo $?)
```

**Output**:

```
1
```

Comment: Quoting the regex is not recommended any more.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns with the following quote: "Be aware that regex parsing in Bash has changed between releases 3.1 and 3.2. Before 3.2 it was safe to wrap your regex pattern in quotes but this has changed in 3.2. Since then, regex should always be unquoted. You should protect any special characters by escaping it using a backslash. The best way to always be compatible is to put your regex in a variable and expand that variable in [[ without quotes, as we showed above. "

Comment: Thanks @EricRenouf

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
[[ "$BOOTPROTO" =~ (static|none|bootp|dhcp)$ ]]
TEST=$?
```

?